# Why was Hiro in his own jail cell after they were arrested?

Tags: plot-explanation, big-hero-6

In the first part of *Big Hero 6*, Hiro is betting on Bot Fighting and is rescued by his brother, Tadashi and subsequently arrested by the police.  The next scene shows Hiro in his own cell while Tadashi, most of the people at the Bot Fights and other people were glaring at him from another cell which was standing room only.

Why was he in his own cell instead of at least in the same cell with his own brother?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Hiro is a **minor** at the time and hence he is designated his own cell while his brother is an **adult** and thus has to share room with the others...

**Tadashi is an adult:** [1](http://disney.wikia.com/wiki/Tadashi_Hamada#Trivia)

> In the film, it is implied that Tadashi is at least of the **age of the majority** (18 years old in the state of California, where Big Hero 6 takes place) because he is in the same cell as the other bot fighters. If he were a minor, he would have been assigned his own cell, as Hiro was.
>
> According to the book Big Hero 6 (Disney Book of Secrets), Tadashi is
>   **18 years old**.

**Hiro is a minor:** [2](http://disney.wikia.com/wiki/Hiro_Hamada#Trivia)

> Hiro graduated high school at the age of 13.

Comment: Hiro is 13 not 14 at the time of bot fighting. Tadashi says "You are graduated from a high school and you're 13 and this is what you're doing?"

Comment: Edited the answer

Comment: Actually, Hiro is 14.  When Hiro can't think of an idea of what to make for the expo, Tadashi says "Wow, washed up at 14".  The quote about high school was "You graduated high school at 13"